# Debug python only using print with minimum typing

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, printing, scope

I want to debug my python program using only print, but I don't want to repeat my self every row.

for e.g, instead of writing:

```
print(f"var1 = {var1}")
print(f"var2 = {var2}")
```

I would like to write:

```
debug(var1, var2) or debug("var1", "var2")
```

and get

```
>>> var1 = 3
>>> var2 = 8
```

I wrote a short function doing this

```
def debug_globals(*vars):
    for var in vars:
        try:
            print(f'{var} = {repr(eval(var))}')
        except NameError as e:
            print(e)
```

It works for globals variables, but won't work for debuging local variables inside a function .

```
>>> x = 2
>>> y = 3

>>> def foo():
...    x = 5
...    debug_globals('x', 'y')
>>> foo()
x = 2
y = 3
```

How can I improve my "debug" function?

Answer (score 1):

The following will probably do what you want:

```
import inspect

def debug(*names):
    out_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    globalz = out_frame.f_globals
    localz  =out_frame.f_locals
    for name in names:
        value = eval(name, globalz, localz)
        print(name, "=", value)
    del out_frame

x = 2
y = 3
debug("x", "y")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Python 3.8's new feature:

```
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> var1 = 3
>>> var2 = 8
>>> print(f'{var1=} {var2=}')
var1=3 var2=8
```